# Truecrypt source code files

Tags: c, visual-studio, build, truecrypt

I recently have built truecrypt source code for windows on Visual 2012. I got 6 files succed, no failed, no skips. But.. there are no output files in "relese" directory which is said there should be in readme file.

ANy idea what's the problem?

## edit

Yeah, I am using files from official truecrypt site.

This is message:

```
6>  Generating Code...
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1137,5): warning MSB8012: TargetPath(C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\tcc\Setup\Debug\Setup.exe) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\tcc\Setup\Debug\TrueCryptSetup.exe). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
6>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(1139,5): warning MSB8012: TargetName(Setup) does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value (TrueCryptSetup). This may cause your project to build incorrectly. To correct this, please make sure that $(OutDir), $(TargetName) and $(TargetExt) property values match the value specified in %(Link.OutputFile).
6>ComSetup.obj : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/SAFESEH' specification
6>  Setup.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\tcc\Setup\Debug\Setup.exe
========== Rebuild All: 6 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Are you sure you was using Release configuration?

Comment: Addded message, maybe it helps.

Comment: It was using debug configuration, when I changed in options to "relese" it showed all the files.. although they are not working :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Debug` configuration, your file is `C:\Users\Artur\Desktop\tcc\Setup\Debug\Setup.exe`

Comment: Ok, agreed, you are right. I'll make another question, because now even they are here they are not working. I hope you can see it and maybe help :)